# Finding Basis $\Bbb{R^4}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find two basis $ \alpha = \{{u_1,u_2}\}$ and $\beta = \{v_1,v_2\}$ for the $ S = \{{ (2r-2s,r-3s,r,s) | r, s \in {R} }\ \} $, so that $u_1$, $u_2$ are not multiples of $v_1$ and $v_2$. $S \subset \mathbb R^4$

Is it possible that a base of  $S \subset \mathbb R^4$ has only 2 vectors? Even though they are $v=(1,1,1,1)$ and $u=(1,0,0,1)$. Wouldn't it take 4 vectors?

I got confused again. Wouldn't Alpha's u1 and u2 be vectors? Because $ \alpha = u_1, u_2$ makes me confused about coordinate vector calculation. that would be, for a w = (1,4).

$$ \displaylines{\begin{bmatrix}
1\
4 \

```
\end{bmatrix} = a \begin{bmatrix}
     6\\
     3 \\
     3 \\
     0    
  \end{bmatrix} +  b  \begin{bmatrix}
     -6\\
     -9\\
     0 \\
     3 
  \end{bmatrix}
```

} $$

Comment: You're after a basis of $S$, not of $\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: But u1 and u2 are vectors that form the basis, correct? Why thinking about a coordinate vector, if $\alpha$ has only 2 vectors, how would it be possible to calculate the coordinate vector of a w = (1,2,3,4) for example with respect to $\alpha$ ?

Comment: $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ of *lower dimension* $2$. So if $w\in S$ then the coordinate vector of $w$ in regards to $\alpha$ has only two components.

Comment: Your question makes no sense, since $(1,2,3,4)\notin S$.

Comment: I think I understand my mistake. Thanks

Comment: I got confused again. Wouldn't Alpha's $u_1$ and $u_2$ be vectors?